# Can a Python thread waiting for a C++ lib to complete freeze the whole application?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, multithreading, gil

I have a Python program, which connects to GigE cameras over the network. These camera connections are established via an external C++ library, called from my Python code. Sometimes connecting to a camera takes a while, which blocks the whole application - which I don't want, because the GUI should still remain responsive.

So I thought I could wrap all the camera connection logic into a Python thread and run the GUI in the main thread. Technically that works, however, now I am wondering: Since the camera connection is established via an external C++ library, could that library fail to release the Python GIL and thus would still freeze the whole application? Or is Python 3.8 smart enough to still hand over the GIL to other threads (the main GUI thread in my case), even if the current thread that has the GIL is waiting for an external C++ library call to complete?

Or in other words: Can Python "force" to take the GIL from a thread that is waiting for an external C++ libary, or does that library have to willingly release the GIL on its own?

If my approach would work, thus if the GIL can be acquired by another thread so that the whole applicaiton would still be responsive even though we are still waiting for the external library call to complete, and this would take too long, is there a way to "kill" this stalling thread completely from the main GUI thread (so that I can try to connect to the camera again or print an error after a timeout or so)?

Comment: How the GIL handling works will depend on the details of the C++ library and how you're invoking it. Your program might lock up, or it might not. We don't have enough information to say either way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I mean exactly that - so it **is** possible that the C++ library might block the whole Python application, even if it is running in another thread? I am not asking if that will happen in my case, of course you cannot answer that. I am interested to know whether it is possible at all that an external library can block the whole application, evren if running in another thread ...

Comment: So I believe your question is: Does calling a C++ function release the GIL? Is that correct?

Comment: @user253751 Yes, I think that's it - sorry if my posting/question is not clear enough.

Comment: It might be easier to manage the threads from C++ instead. The C++ thread support is far more robust. Write a thin C++ layer wrapping your camera library; it can start a C++ thread when necessary. Calls to the wrapper will return quickly, so the GIL doesn't really matter anymore.